# updating fulltext search index

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is it possible to update a fulltext search index? I can't find anything in the documentation state for or against it.

E.g.

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.createNodeIndex(
        "FullTextIndex",
        [
            "Node"
        ],
        [
            "title", 
            "description"
        ]);
```

If I wanted to update either the label or property, is there any way to do so without dropping and rebuilding it?

Comment: I highly doubt it

Comment: You cannot expect an API to document everything it does not support (since the documentation would then have to be infinitely long). It is therefore prudent to assume that the API only supports what *is* documented (unless you have good reason to suspect otherwise).

Comment: @cybersam documentation gets out of date or gets left out all of the time.

Comment: @cybersam is there any recommended method to updating fulltext indices? Or is the process to just create a brand new index then use that instead?

Comment: You should just [drop](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/administration/indexes-for-full-text-search/index.html#administration-indexes-fulltext-search-drop) the existing index and create a new one.